# Abrir nueva ventana con java fxml sin usar botón

Tags: java, fxml

Estoy intentando crear un sistema de log in desde 0 y no soy capaz de abrir una nueva ventana una vez he recibido la respuesta del servidor. Consigo hacer un cambio de ventana a través de un botón de prueba que he hecho pero no a través del método del hilo, que es el que recibe la respuesta del servidor. El error que me da es:

> Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:280)
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:444)
> at javafx.stage.Stage.(Stage.java:241)
> at javafx.stage.Stage.(Stage.java:227)
> at pf_aplicacioncliente.FXMLDocumentController.cambiaVentana(FXMLDocumentController.java:106)
> at pf_aplicacioncliente.HiloAppCliente.run(HiloAppCliente.java:74)

Soy muy nuevo, no sean muy duros con mi código xD

Controller:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TextField user;
    @FXML
    private TextField pass;
    @FXML
    private Text respuesta;
    @FXML
    private Button cambio;

    HiloAppCliente h;
    PaqueteEnvio datos;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        try {
            h = new HiloAppCliente(respuesta);
            h.start();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Falla aqui");
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void acceder(ActionEvent event) {  //opcion 2 

        try {
            datos = new PaqueteEnvio();
            datos.setUser(user.getText());
            datos.setPass(pass.getText());
            datos.setOpcion(2);
            
            h.enviar(datos);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void registrar(ActionEvent event) { //opcion 1

        try {
            datos = new PaqueteEnvio();
            datos.setUser(user.getText());
            datos.setPass(pass.getText());
            datos.setOpcion(1);

            h.enviar(datos);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void cambiaVentana() {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXML_Programa.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            FXML_ProgramaController controlador = loader.getController();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            
            Stage oldStage = (Stage) this.respuesta.getScene().getWindow();
            oldStage.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Hilo:

```
public class HiloAppCliente extends Thread {

    private SocketFactory factory = (SocketFactory) SocketFactory.getDefault();
    Socket cliente;//Socket cliente;

    final String SERVER = "localhost";
    final int PUERTO = 2020;

    ObjectInputStream recibir;
    ObjectOutputStream enviar;
    PaqueteEnvio paquete;
    Text respuesta;

    public HiloAppCliente(Text respuesta) throws IOException {

        cliente = (Socket) factory.createSocket(SERVER, PUERTO);
        enviar = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        recibir = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
        this.respuesta = respuesta;

    }

    public void enviar(PaqueteEnvio envio) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            enviar.writeObject(envio);
            System.out.println("Mensaje: " + envio);
            enviar.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HiloAppCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            try {

                paquete = (PaqueteEnvio) recibir.readObject();

                if (paquete.getOpcion() == 3) {

                    System.out.println("Imprime cliente: " + paquete.getRespuesta());
                    respuesta.setText(paquete.getRespuesta());
                
                } else if (paquete.getOpcion() == 4) {
                    System.out.println("Respuesta recibida para que cambie de ventana");
                    
                    FXMLDocumentController cambia = new FXMLDocumentController();
                    cambia.cambiaVentana();
                    
                }

            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HiloAppCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Podrías compartir el código donde creas e inicias el hilo?

Comment: Lo creo en el controller (que ya esta compartido), lo llamo h y lo instacio en el método initialize. Gracias de antemano